How to fix ubuntu-drivers python script error
sudo ubuntu-drivers install for installing proprietary NVIDIA graphics drivers fails with a type mismatch error in detect.py script. How do I fix this?

No release details; or context is provided in this question. Providing clear details & paste of the problem may help, but the question as outlined can have multiple causes and so few specifics were provided.

Attempting to replace nouveau with nvidia driver on Ubuntu 22.04
uname -r -> 6.8.0-40-generic
All of the following is done using sudo -s command.
Needed to add ppa repositories for nvidia drivers.
Needed apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-drivers-common
Reinstall ubuntu-drivers apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
ubuntu-drivers install failed with python error of type mismatch between int and string for >= operator.
Needed to update file:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
 --- detect.py_orig 2023-09-15 04:59:17.000000000 -0400 
 +++ detect.py  2024-08-28 19:39:37.732876934 -0400
 @@ -969,7 +969,7 @@
     # Enable KMS if nvidia >= 470
     for package_name in to_install:
         nvidia_info = NvidiaPkgNameInfo(package_name)
 -        if nvidia_info.get_major_version() >= 470:
 +        if int(nvidia_info.get_major_version()) >= 470:
             set_nvidia_kms(1)
             return


This might be an answer but your question as written makes no sense. Please edit the question and fill in some details as already asked.
